# How to Convert Multiple Columns into Rows in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to generate dataset that looks like as shown in the last table.
Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thank you
[image]

Comment: See [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
Set up temp table to work off
*/

create table #temp 
(a decimal(10,2), 
b decimal(10,2), 
c decimal(10,2), 
d decimal(10,2), 
e decimal(10,2), 
f decimal(10,2), 
dollor decimal(10,2),
YrQtr nvarchar(7))

insert #temp values
(105,5,8,51,40,15,29039.56,'2012-Q4'),
(109,5,5,49,40,14,16116.72,'2013-Q1'),
(109,4,4,55,41,22,21988.31,'2013-Q2'),
(105,3,4,52,36,21,14971.17,'2013-Q3'),
(93,3,2,47,35,18,25862.77,'2013-Q4')

*/



select 
    [Measure],[2012-Q4], [2013-Q1],  [2013-Q2], [2013-Q3], [2013-Q4] 
from(
    select A, B, C,  D, E, F, Dollor [zDollar],YrQtr
    from #temp)    as Source 
    UNPIVOT (
       vals   
       for [Measure] in([A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F],[zDollar])
)as [unpivoted] 
pivot (
max(vals) 
for YrQtr in ([2012-Q4], [2013-Q1],  [2013-Q2], [2013-Q3], [2013-Q4]) 
) as t
```

One thing to note is that this script will order the resulting measures alphabetically - so it would be `A,B,C,D,Dollor,E,F` rather than the likely desired `A,B,C,D,E,F,Dollor`. To make it more simple for now, I just aliased the `Dollar` column to force it to the end of the list.

Comment: Tom, thank you. Thats exactly what I wanted to accomplish. One thing though how do I get rid of .00 from measure (A-F). Thank you

Comment: Oh ya, I forgot to mention that - the pivot columns have to be the same type, so I had to change the column from int to decimal.   Not sure how you can get around this, as the column can be either one or the other, but not both

Comment: Thank you Tom, what I did was instead of changing to decimal data type, I just changed Dollar column to Int ( all other columns are Int). That way I dont have to worry about the trailing zeros. Dollar columns gives me rounded figure which is just fine. Once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tom, thank you, 
I RETURN THE QUERY AS BELOW

```
DECLARE  @TEMPQUES TABLE(MaxRange NVARCHAR(MAX),MinRange NVARCHAR(MAX),ReferenceTypeName NVARCHAR(MAX),Instructions NVARCHAR(MAX),Question NVARCHAR(MAX))
insert into @TEMPQUES
SELECT CAST(MaxRange AS nVARCHAR(100)),CAST(MinRange AS NVARCHAR(100)),QuestionnaireReferenceTypeName,Instructions,Question FROM vw_QuestionnaireAnswers WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE QuestionnaireID = 100000

SELECT [QA],[Dimenssion],[Is Material in good packing],[NCR],[Special remarks],[Length] FROM
(SELECT ISNULL(MaxRange,0)  AS MaxRange,ISNULL(MinRange,0) AS MinRange,
        ISNULL(ReferenceTypeName,'NA') AS ReferenceTypeName
        ,ISNULL(Instructions,'NA') AS Instructions,Question 
FROM @TEMPQUES ) AS Questionnaire
UNPIVOT( VALUE FOR [QA] IN([MaxRange],[MinRange],[ReferenceTypeName],[Instructions])
) AS [UNPIVOTED]
PIVOT(MAX(VALUE) FOR Question  IN  ([Dimenssion],[Is Material in good packing],[NCR],[Special remarks],[Length] ) )  AS PVTTable
```